# Sharing Azure KayVault secret with external users

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I created an Azure KayVault and manually added a value to the secrets.
Now, I want to share that manually added Secret with someone who is external to the organization, (they won't be having access to our Azure subscription)
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for external users to get Azure KayVault secret without any Access policy.

I invite the external user first.

[image]

Then add access policy for it.

[image]

Test with Python:

Use `az login --allow-no-subscriptions` to sign the invited user in.

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential

keyvault_credential= AzureCliCredential()

secret_client = SecretClient("https://pamelakeyv.vault.azure.net", keyvault_credential)
secret = secret_client.get_secret("test")

print(secret.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Pamela! Do you know if no-subscription users can access the secrets through the portal once they are included in the access policy? Also, how to allow no-subscription users through the user interface (Azure portal)?

Comment: I tried in the portal but it showed "You do not have any Azure subscriptions in the xxx directory. " in Notifications.